# log4javascript - obtain history of messages programmatically?

Tags: log4javascript

I'm looking into using a javascript logging framework in my app.

I quite like the look of log4javascript (http://log4javascript.org/) but I have one requirement which I'm not sure that it satisfies.

I need to be able to ask the framework for all messages which have been logged.

Perhaps I could use an invisible InPageAppender (http://log4javascript.org/docs/manual.html#appenders) to log to a DOM element, then scrape out  the messages from that DOM element - but that seems pretty heavy.

Perhaps I need to write my own "InMemoryAppender"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an `ArrayAppender` used in log4javascript's unit tests that stores all log messages it receives in an array accessible via its `logMessages` property. Hopefully it should show up in the main distribution in the next version. Here's a standalone implementation:

```
var ArrayAppender = function(layout) {
    if (layout) {
        this.setLayout(layout);
    }
    this.logMessages = [];
};

ArrayAppender.prototype = new log4javascript.Appender();

ArrayAppender.prototype.layout = new log4javascript.NullLayout();

ArrayAppender.prototype.append = function(loggingEvent) {
    var formattedMessage = this.getLayout().format(loggingEvent);
    if (this.getLayout().ignoresThrowable()) {
        formattedMessage += loggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep();
    }
    this.logMessages.push(formattedMessage);
};

ArrayAppender.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "[ArrayAppender]";
};
```

Example use:

```
var log = log4javascript.getLogger("main");
var appender = new ArrayAppender();
log.addAppender(appender);
log.debug("A message");
alert(appender.logMessages);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Tim. Looking forward to that next version. I've done something home-baked & very light-weight in the meantime.